# JMeter plugins - uninstall plugin without upgrade others

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

About JMeter plugins Manger,

When I want to uninstall a plugin It still forces me to upgrade my existing plugins (if exists):
[image]
Is there a way do uninstall plugins without upgrading others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by switching to Upgrades tab:

[image]

And uncheck the plugin that you don't want to upgrade.

The update disappears:

[image]